# Arrowhead color in Asymptote

Tags: arrows, 3d, asymptote

Let's consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article} 
\usepackage{asymptote} 
\begin{document} 
\begin{asy} 
settings.outformat = "pdf"; 
settings.prc= false; 
settings.render = 0; 
import three; 
size(5cm, 0); 
currentprojection=orthographic((5,1,1)); 

draw(O -- X, arrow=Arrow3(TeXHead2, emissive(green)), 
p=green+linewidth(1pt)); 

\end{asy} 
\end{document}
```

The separated line was taken from the manual. Instead, the output looks like this:

[image]

You can see that the arrowhead is black and definitely not green. If I change the value of `settings.render` into 8 or 16, the arrow becomes green.

Meanwhile, I simply must have a vector graphics, so `settings.render = 0;` can't be changed. Is there any way to have *color vector* arrowheads? Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Please find a workaround (I don't know if it is a bug or not)

```
size(5cm, 0);
currentprojection=orthographic((5,1,1)); 

draw(O -- X, arrow=Arrow3(TeXHead2(),Fill,emissive(green)), 
     p=green+linewidth(1pt));
```

[image]

O.G.